# Plugin settings - file field upload location

Tags: plugin-development, plugins, settings

My plugin needs to allow admin to upload an image. I have the field setup and saving ok. But i cant seem to control the upload location.

This is what i have so far in my settings:

```
{{ forms.file({
    label: "My Image"|t,
    instructions: ""|t,
    name: 'myImage',
    value: settings.myImage
}) }}
```

When I output the `settings.myImage`, I get the file name on its own and no path. I would like it to upload to my `/uploads` folder.
So for example, the image I uploaded was "test.jpg". When I output the result of `settings.myImage`, I get "test.jpg" and no path.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Unfortunately, a simple HTML file input on its own isn't enough to upload an image (in Craft or anywhere else) – the input simply exposes the file on your local filesystem to the browser/server. In other words, with your current setup, you're not actually uploading anything.

In my opinion, you have two choices:

1. Use Assets and Craft's built-in Assets ElementSelect input (easy)
2. Don't use Assets; upload the image natively using a file input (harder)

Personally, I'd recommend that unless you *can't* have the image be an Asset file for some reason, you should definitely go with the Assets approach. It's way easier to set up, offers a familiar user experience and you can even use image transforms and whatnot since your `myImage` file will be a bona fide Asset.

Either way, here's how option 1 could look:

In your plugin's `settings.html` file, replace your current call to the `forms.file()` macro with this:

```
{{ forms.field({
  label: "My Image"
}, include('_includes/forms/elementSelect', myImageSelectConfig)) }}
```

Then, fire up your plugin's primary class. Revise your `getSettingsHtml()` method to include the `myImageSelectConfig` attribute referenced in `settings.html` above, so the method looks something like this:

```
public function getSettingsHtml()
{
    return craft()->templates->render('yourpluginhandle/settings', array(
        'settings' => $this->getSettings(),
        'myImageSelectConfig' => array(
            'id'                 => 'myImage',
            'name'               => 'myImage',
            'jsClass'            => 'Craft.AssetSelectInput',
            'elementType'        => new ElementTypeVariable(craft()->elements->getElementType(ElementType::Asset)),
            'elements'           => $this->getSettings()['myImage'] ? craft()->elements->getCriteria(ElementType::Asset, array('id' => $this->getSettings()['myImage'])) : null,
            'sources'            => array('folder:2'),
            'criteria'           => array('kind' => array('image'), 'localeEnabled' => null),
            'limit'              => 1,
            'viewMode'           => 'table',
            'selectionLabel'     => Craft::t('Add image'),
        ),
    ));
}
```

Note: The `sources` attribute refers to the ID(s) for the Asset folder the admin should upload images to (and choose images from). You can look at the `craft_assetfolders` database table to figure out which ID(s) you want. Alternatively you can remove the `sources` property entirely, to enable all folders – which is probably the best option if this is going to be a publicly available plugin.

And that's it. The actual `myImage` setting value stored will be an array with the ID to the selected Asset file, e.g. `{"myImage":["42"]}`. If you need to pull the Asset in a template, you'll need to add a [Variable](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/plugins/variables) class to your plugin, exposing the plugin settings:

```
class MyPluginVariable
{
    public function settings()
    {
        return craft()->plugins->getPlugin('myPlugin')->getSettings();
    }
}
```

...and in your template:

```
{% set assetId = craft.myPlugin.settings.myImage %}
{% set asset = craft.assets.id(assetId).first() %}
```

**If you don't want to go with the Assets approach**, you can keep your `forms.file()` macro in `settings.html`. However, there's a few more things you'll need to handle to get the upload working.

First, in order to actually upload a file from a file input, the enclosing form needs to have an `enctype="multipart/form-data"` attribute. Unfortunately, plugin settings forms don't, and there's no real way to add it. However, you can use jQuery to hack it in – add this to your plugin's `settings.html` file:

```
{% includeJs '$("form:first").attr("enctype", "multipart/form-data");' %}
```

Second, you'll need some server side code to actually handle the upload. Add the following to your plugin's primary class:

```
public function prepSettings($settings)
{

    $imageFile = UploadedFile::getInstanceByName('settings.myImage');

    if ($imageFile) {

        // Where should the image be stored?
        $basePath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
        $uploadFolder = '/uploads/yourpluginhandle/';
        $filePath = $basePath.$uploadFolder.$imageFile->name;

        // Make sure the upload folder exists
        IOHelper::ensureFolderExists($basePath.$uploadFolder);

        // Attempt to upload the file
        if ($imageFile->saveAs($filePath)) {
            // File uploaded successfully – store the relative filepath in the plugin settings
            $settings['myImage'] = str_replace($basePath, '', $filePath);
        } else {
            // Aw.
            craft()->userSession->setError(Craft::t('Unable to upload image {filename}', array(
                'filename' => $imageFile->name,
            )));
        }
    }

    return $settings;

}
```

The above example is pretty much the bare minimum you'd need in order to upload a file from your plugin's settings page, to an arbitrary folder on your server's file system. The example `prepSettings()` script will upload the file to a folder called `/uploads/yourpluginhandle` in the public webroot (i.e. `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`), before storing the *relative* path to the file in the settings, if the upload was successful.

Keep in mind that file uploading is actually fairly complex (lots of things can go wrong), and also a potential security risk. You should probably consider adding some code to ensure that the file's mime type (`$imageFile->type`), size (`$imageFile->size`) and other properties are legit, before calling `$file->saveAs()`. You might also need to create a UI for displaying and deleting the current image, and making sure old and no longer selected files are deleted from the server.

Finally, I'd posit that a vanilla browser file input is a pretty terrible user experience, compared to the Assets select input in Craft proper. There's all sorts of JavaScript libraries to help out with that, of course – in any case the above is hopefully a good starting point if you go down this road.

Comment: Seriously, though... I want to fly to Norway just to buy you a beer.

Comment: @BradBell That's fortunate - I love beer!

Comment: No worries, @BillyMedia – hope it helps you out.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone wanting to do this in Craft 3 there are a couple changes to the code you need to add to getSettingsHtml().

```
'myImageSelectConfig' => array(
            'id'                 => 'myImage',
            'name'               => 'myImage',
            'jsClass'            => 'Craft.AssetSelectInput',
            'elementType'        => 'craft\\elements\\Asset',
            'elements'           => $this->getSettings()['myImage'] && count($this->getSettings()['myImage']) ? [Craft::$app->getElements()->getElementById($this->getSettings()['myImage'][0])] : null,
            'sources'            => array('folder:2'),
            'criteria'           => array('kind' => array('image'), 'localeEnabled' => null),
            'limit'              => 1,
            'viewMode'           => 'table',
            'selectionLabel'     => Craft::t('app','Add image'),
        )
```